# List users with specific child value in a ListView Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to list all the users where child `session: 2011` from the Firebase Realtime Database into a ListView. This is my data structure:

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "uid1" : {
      "name" : "Jhon",
      "session" : 2011
    },
    "uid2" : {
      "name" : "Kim",
      "session" : 2011
    }
  }
}
```

This is my list activity:

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    FirebaseListAdapter adapter;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String userID = user.getUid();
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        ref.child(userID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String session = dataSnapshot.child("session").getValue().toString();
                if (session.equals("2011")) {
                    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

                    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                    FirebaseListOptions < profile > options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder < profile > ()
                        .setLayout(R.layout.profile)
                        .setQuery(query, profile.class)
                        .build();
                    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter(options) {
                        @Override
                        protected void populateView(View v, Object model, int position) {
                            TextView name = v.findViewById(R.id.name);
                            TextView session = v.findViewById(R.id.session);

                            profile user = (profile) model;
                            name.setText("Name: " + user.getName().toString());
                            session.setText("Session: " + user.getSession().toString());
                        }
                    };
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                } else {
                    //
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And this is my `profile` class:

```
public class profile {
    private String name;
    private String session;

    public profile() {}

    public profile(String name, String session) {
        this.name = name;
        this.session = session;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSession() {
        return session;
    }

    public void setSession(String session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

}
```

But the problem is, it is not returning anything. What am I missing here?

For referrence, I have tried the following, but when I did this, it only returned the value of the user that is currently signed in. Nothing else.

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
FirebaseListOptions < profile > options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder < profile > ()
    .setLayout(R.layout.profile)
    .setLifecycleOwner(IdCheckActivity.this)
    .setQuery(query, profile.class)
    .build();
adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter(options) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View v, Object model, int position) {
        TextView name = v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView session = v.findViewById(R.id.session);

        profile user = (profile) model;
        name.setText("Name: " + user.getName().toString());
        session.setText("Session: " + user.getSession().toString());
    }
};
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    adapter.startListening();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Query` you can very well use `DatabaseReference`, and with the help of `orderByChild()`, it can be done like this:

```java
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();



rootRef.child("Users").orderByChild("session").equalTo(2011).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String tempName = data.child("name").getValue(String.class);

                   //with tempName you can access their usernames and you will only get the usernames with session 2011, so you can directly populate your listView from here and use it

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

The `tempName` variable will only get the `name` of the `Users` child, with `session` as 2011. Also if 2011 is stored as `String`, use it like "2011".

**Edit:** Also if you are not listening to the changes and just want to see if such `User` exists then you can use `if(dataSnapshot.exists())` in the `valueEventListener()`.

To populate the `listView` using this code is simple and very much alike to what you'd do, and it looks like this:

```java
ArrayList array = new ArrayList<String>;
ListView listView;

//set the findViewById for the listView

//add the following code in the valueEventListener

array.add(tempName);

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(YourActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for the answer. Would very much helpful if you can update the answer with the codes to populate the listview for this example.